# Secure coding in go

Tags: linux, security, go

I'm starting to learn go and I've been unable to find any guidelines regarding secure coding in go, such as exist for many other programming languages.

I'm wondering if anyone can point me to anything like this for go, or tell me what guidelines from other languages might most apply.

I'll mostly be writing webapps running on linux.

cheers

Comment: All general advice also holds for Go. The most important advice for Go: Check your return values and do proper error handling!